# Loading data into snowflake containing XML datatype

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can someone help me to solve this error?

**TABLE :** CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "SANDY"."CUSTOMER" ("CID" BIGINT NOT NULL,"INFO" VARIANT,"HISTORY" VARIANT);
**FILE FORMAT :** XML

```sh
SANDY#COMPUTE_WH@SAMPLE_DB.USER> COPY INTO CUSTOMER FROM @my_stage_name/customer.xml;
```

> 002019 (0A000): SQL compilation error:
> XML file format can produce one and only one column of type variant or object or array. Use CSV file format if you want to load more than one column.

Comment: Please provide the create statements for the target table and the file format you are using

Comment: Have a look [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/introduction-to-loading-and-parsing-xml-data-using-sql) for some examples.